# ValueError: exceeds max_bin_len() when attempting spacy.load()

Tags: spacy

I installed spacy using

```
python3 install spacy
```

and downladed two English models using

```
python3 -m spacy download en
```

and

```
python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

When I attempt to load any one of them with

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
```

I get

```
  File "msgpack/_unpacker.pyx", line 187, in msgpack._cmsgpack.unpackb
ValueError: 1792000 exceeds max_bin_len(1048576)
```

Googling didn't help me at all and I don't understand what the error is. I'd be thankful for any pointers.

Comment: This is likely related to an update of the `msgpack` dependency, which was released today. See here for more details: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2995

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [issue](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2995) was caused by a change in the `msgpack` package.

spacy has released a fix in version 2.0.18

To fix, update to the spacy verion:

```
pip install spacy==2.0.18
```

Answer (score 9):

try pip install msgpack==0.5.6

Answer (score 0):

Update spacy after install language. The problem is the msgpack 0.6.0.

Try:

```
python -m spacy download en
pip install -U spacy
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the only thing that worked was to change in my requirements.txt file, 
from:

```
msgpack-python==0.5.4
```

To:

```
msgpack==0.5.6
```

and then:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Or just (if you don't use requirements file):

```
pip install msgpack==0.5.6
```